# ruby LoadError for .so file

Tags: ruby, embedded-linux, ld

I'm working with ruby1.8.7 on an embedded platform, and I'm trying to port the ruby sqlite3 gem onto the platform.

The underlying sqlite3_native.so makes successfully, and is installed on the target. ldd indicates that all dependencies are met. However, when I try to load it, I get a LoadError (File not Found). Other .so libraries in the same directory load successfully.

```
#ls -l
total 167
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Oct 10 16:24 di.so -> di.so.5
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         16540 Oct 10 15:29 di.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root         37916 Mar  6  2012 serialport.so
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root         51375 Oct 16 17:25 sqlite3_native.so

#[path_to_ruby]/bin/ruby -r ./di -e exit
#
#[path_to_ruby]/bin/ruby -r ./serialport -e exit
#
#[path_to_ruby]/bin/ruby -r ./ssqlite3_native -e exit
./sqlite3_native.so: File not found - ./sqlite3_native.so (LoadError)
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on possible causes?

Kind regards

Steve

Answer (score 1):

The power of taking a walk to clear one's head....

The issue is in the linking of the  library in the make process, not on the target machine.

The mkmf generated makefile links in `libruby.so` via the line

```
LIBS = $(LIBRUBYARG_SHARED) -lsqlite3  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
```

removing libruby ( `$(LIBRUBYARG_SHARED)` ) changes the generated library in some subtle way (it is 20 bytes smaller) which then allows the ruby executable to locate and load the library.